# Encode categorical data

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoding, scikit-learn

I am trying to encode the `company_names` in my dataset, I tried using 
`pd.get_dummies(Data['Company_share_code'])` and also with

```
# X=data.iloc[:,0].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder

labelencoder=LabelEncoder()
Data['Company_share_code']=labelencoder.fit_transform(Data['Company_share_code'])

#One hot encoding

Onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])
Onehotencoder.fit_transform(Data['Company_share_code'])
```

But I'm getting this error -

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py in _handle_deprecations(self, X)
    392                     "use the ColumnTransformer instead.", DeprecationWarning)
    393                 # Set categories_ to empty list if no categorical columns exist
--> 394                 n_features = X.shape[1]
    395                 sel = np.zeros(n_features, dtype=bool)
    396                 sel[np.asarray(self.categorical_features)] = True

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: are you facing this issue in `OneHotEncoder` or `LabelEncoder`

Comment: @jeril in `oneHotencoder`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```
Onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])
Onehotencoder.fit_transform(Data['Company_share_code'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Which will give you a sparse matrix. You can convert it to dense using `todense()`

See below for a toy example

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder


Data = pd.DataFrame({'Company_share_code' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A']})

labelencoder=LabelEncoder()
Data['Company_share_code']=labelencoder.fit_transform(Data['Company_share_code'])

#One hot encoding

Onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])
h = Onehotencoder.fit_transform(Data['Company_share_code'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

h.todense()

# Output
matrix([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.]])
```